# What is the data type of 'emp::regclass'?

Tags: postgresql

There is this question that is important to answer.
I tend to think that since 'regclass' is an alias for OID the answer is 'OID'.
Am I right here?
Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`regclass` and the other `reg` types are "[object identifier types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html)". As the documentation says:

> The `oid` type is currently implemented as an unsigned four-byte integer.
>
> [...]
>
> The OID alias types have no operations of their own except for specialized input and output routines. These routines are able to accept and display symbolic names for system objects, rather than the raw numeric value that type `oid` would use.

So it is just a convenience: it really is the numeric object ID, but is displayed as the object name.

`regclass` can be cast to numerical data types: then it will become the `oid` value.

`regclass` can also be cast to `text`: then it will become the table name.